# Django, register extended user model

Tags: python, django, django-registration, django-users

I have extended djago's user model to a model **teachers**. Teachers have 3 fields:

- user (one to one field to user)
- modules (many to many field to module)
- confirmed (boolean)

So I got a registration forms which works for non-teachers, and copied it for teachers. I'm trying to save the 3 extra fields of teachers when the user register from the teacher registration form.

The registration should work since it's the same form with normal users but it has to save the 3 additional field of **teacher**.

I read that since `modules` is a `ManyToManyField` I have to use `save_m2m()` but I don't know how to get the value of the field(select multiple) from the form.

models.py

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    modules = models.ManyToManyField(Module)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationFormTeacher(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    modules = forms.SelectMultiple()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationFormTeacher, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

views.py

```
def register_teacher(request):
    args = {}
    universities = University.objects.order_by('name').distinct()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationFormTeacher(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_teacher = form.save(commit=False)
            new_teacher.modules = form.cleaned_data['modules']
            new_teacher.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard_teacher'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationFormTeacher()
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response("registration/registration_form_teacher.html", {'universities': universities}, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: So where is the data for those fields supposed to be coming from? You haven't included them in the form.

Comment: I keep reading questions and tutorials so got confused and thought I should post a clean view.

Comment: But you at least need to show the relevant information. At the moment, despite the name, RegistrationFormTeacher only deals with User information. Where is the Teacher data (eg modules) coming from? How do you want it to get into the model?

Comment: I updated the question and added some code that takes the `modules` values from the form. And then it has to save them. But I don't know how to make it save it to the **Teacher** instance.

Comment: No, that's nonsense. The form does not have a `modules` field, as far as you have shown. If you want help, you need to show your actual code.

Comment: I really do not have more code about this one. I wish I had! I have no reason to hide code. Just looking for a way to implement the registration of **teachers**.

Comment: Sigh. Last attempt then. **You do not have a modules field on that form**. Where is the data supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Sorry if I got you confused but I'm new to Django & Python. I tried to add 2 models to the form Meta but of course it's not correct. So I added `modules = forms.SelectMultiple()` to the form. Wish I could have more code to show you. Here's also my `forms.py`: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cDKaeFeG).

Comment: You have `fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')` in your form. You need to add modules to the tuple.

Comment: Exactly! But the things is that modules belong to a different model. Any ideas on how to do that? I tried to write Model=User, Teacher but it's working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a `Teacher` model but your modelform's model is `User` - so you're not saving what you want in the way you want.

The absolute easiest, but not necessarily the most elegant, way to do this is with two separate forms.

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')


class RegistrationFormTeacher(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = (modules, confirmed)
```

Then when you're processing your RegistrationFormTeacher:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationFormTeacher(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_teacher = form.save(commit=False)
        new_teacher.user = request.user #get the user object however you want - you 
            #can pass the user ID to the view as a parameter and do 
            #User.objects.get(pk=id) or some such, too. 
        new_teacher.save()
        form.save_m2m()
```